# how to solve error while run flutter get pub

Tags: flutter

`C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Elite quiz\Elite Quiz Flutter Code v-2.0.7\elite-quiz-2.0.7>flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (4.4s)
Because flutterquiz depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.1, intl 0.18.1 is required.
So, because flutterquiz depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.

You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:

- Try upgrading your constraint on intl: flutter pub add intl:^0.18.1`

how to solve it, i'm getting while i run flutter pub get

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you have to upgrade intl package to version 0.18.1 like this to solve the conflict:

```
intl: ^0.18.1
```

If it fails again you can use it like this:

```
intl:
```